# how to do encryption with "java script" and decryption with and "java"

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the "url" in java script by using below method

```js
var s='';
for(var i=0;i<origUrl.length;i++)
{
    var c=origUrl.charCodeAt(i);

    if(c != ' ')
    {
        c=String.fromCharCode(c + 47);

        if( c > '~')
        {
            c=String.fromCharCode(c - 94); 
        }
    }
    s=s.concat(c);
}
```

and for decryption in java I am using below code

```java
 public static String rotate(String value)
    {
      int length = value.length();
      String result = "";

      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
        char c = value.charAt(i);

        // Process letters, numbers, and symbols -- ignore spaces.
        if (c != ' ')
        { 
          c += 47;

          if (c > '~')
            c -= 94;
        }

        result=result+c;
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Both code has same logic but it is not working for me, means when I am passing java script generated string to server side and doing decryption, I am not getting the correct string which I am expecting.

on other hand if I am executing this logic in java standalone application then it is working for me.

Please check below

```java
String url = "https://abcd.com";

System.out.println(url);

String encode = rotate(url);

System.out.println(encode);

String decode = rotate(encode);

System.out.println(decode);
```

and output

```
https://abcd.com
9EEADi^^2345]4@>
https://abcd.com
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: So what do you get if you run both the javascript and the java together?

Comment: " it is not working for me" - can you please clarify?

Comment: I have updated ..

Comment: Can you update with the actual string the javascript is creating?

Comment: Where is `c` defined in your javascript?

Comment: jonhopkins, shmosel, krease, thanks for reply, I have updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function rotate(x)
{
var s=[];
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  var j=x.charCodeAt(i);
  if((j>=33)&&(j<=126))
  {
   s[i]=String.fromCharCode(33+((j+14)%94));
  }
  else
  {
   s[i]=String.fromCharCode(j);
  }
}
return s.join('');

}
```

Comment: it is correct answer

Answer (score 1):

your javascript code is incorrect....
i am getting the garbage value...

```
    <script>
    function getval(origUrl){
    ///from here 
    var s='';
    for(var i=0;i<origUrl.length;i++)
    {
        var j=origUrl.charCodeAt(i); // here in you are storing integer in j.
        var k='';
        if(j != ' ')  // don't compare " " with j because j contains integer
        {
            k=String.fromCharCode(j + 47);

            if( j > '~') // here too j contains integer...
///you cann use String.fromCharCode(j); that is ok
            {
                k=String.fromCharCode(c - 94); //where the variable c is declared???
            }
        }
        s=s.concat(k);
    }
    // upto here source code is same...as you provided...
    return s;
    }

    var text="https://abcd.com";
    alert(text);
    alert(getval(text));
    alert(getval(getval(text)));
    </script>
```

Comment: That's not what the problem is. If you notice at the end of the question, the same function is being used for the encryption and decryption and getting the correct output. There's a reason the function is called "rotate" and not "encrypt" or "decrypt"

Comment: let me check this thing out...

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your JavaScript code, both of which are in the innermost `if` block.

```
if( j > '~')
{
    k=String.fromCharCode(c - 94); 
}
```

First off, you are checking if `j` is bigger than `'~'`. That's *almost* what you want. Since `j` isn't the variable that's actually changing here, you should instead be checking if `k > '~'`.

Second, you have a variable called `c` inside that `if` block that doesn't exist anywhere else. I am guessing you copied and pasted from the Java to the Javascript and forgot to rename that variable. Again, what you need it to be is `k`. Additionally, because `k` is a string, you need to get the `charCode` from it.

With these problems in mind, that `if` block should become this:

```
if (k > '~')
{
    k = String.fromCharCode(k.charCodeAt(0) - 94); 
}
```

Comment: jonhopkins thanks for your effort :) , I have gotten the corresponding java script method, you can check in posts